# What is the value of $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin[(n + \frac{1}{2})t]}{\sin(t)}dt$, where $n$ is a natural number?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

What is the value of $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin[(n + \frac{1}{2})t]}{\sin(t)}dt$, where $n$ is a natural number?

Comment: How are you getting it?

Comment: Is the denominator supposed to be $\sin(t/2)$? If so, see the wikipedia page on the Dirichlet Kernel.

Comment: The answer is not $\pi$. It is $\pi$ if the denominator is $\sin(t/2)$.

Comment: I agree with Mhenni.

Comment: How to proceed? Anybody?

Comment: Can you give some context ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#Higher_odd_powers_of_secant

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, the integrand has a pole of order one at $t=\pi$ as Laurent series shows that

> $$ -\sin \left(  ( n+{1}/{2} ) \pi  \right)\left( t-
> \pi  \right)^{-1}-c_1 + c_2  \left( 
> t-\pi  \right) +O (  ( t-\pi  ) ^{2} ).$$